# Javascript Return Result of jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

**The Problem**

I am trying to return the result of jQuery's `getJSON` method.

**What I've Tried**

I under stand that the getJSON method is asynchronous, and that I cannot simply return the result as you can with synchronous code.

I've looked at other posts and I tried messing around with promises, as well as callbacks, etc... but have gotten nowhere.

**My Code (Before Trying Promises, Callbacks, Etc...)**

```
function getCart() {
  jQuery.getJSON("/cart.js").done(function (cart) {
      return cart;
  });
}

cart = getCart();
console.log(cart);
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you execute your code after the promise is resolved? Just return the promise from the function `return jQuery.getJSON("/cart.js");` and then `getCart().done(function(cart) { console.log(cart) });`